# determining if my multimeter is functioning correctly

Tags: electrical, multimeter

Am using a multimeter to check some circuits.  All the breakers show a 1 or .9 at the hot terminal to ground, which i assume means 100 volts, 90 volts. Everything is working correctly.  I checked at individual outlets and get 1.20, or 120.  I suppose this could be some interference in the panel since theres so much in there?  its a cheapo multimeter.

other item, ive been checking resistance and get different readings on the same stuff if i switch the leads, which seems like it shouldnt be for resistence check.  set me straight, thanks in advance.

edit.  it's set correctly and reads correct voltages at known outlets.  yet the breaker terminal to reads 25 volts below it.  As the known tested outlets on same settings read correctly, and  voltage uppage is conventionally not feasible im trying to understand this.

edit:  the only way i could see voltage rising is crossed curcuit wiring, but that's not the case, so im looking at the panel for clues.

Comment: Please edit in pictures. Most likely given the reported readings it's set wrong, or is a hopeless hunk of junk. Cheap and functional is possible to obtain, but far from guaranteed.

Comment: Check the range you have the meter set to.  It seems you have set to a high range(1K volts instead of 200 volts)  The differences should not be that great, so maybe get a better quality of meter.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a junky meter. A couple of things: 1 - If you touch the leads together in resistance/Ohms mode it should (depending on the meter) either show 0 Ohms or beep for continuity (or both). 2 - You're probably OK, but beware that technically speaking for safety you should only use a UL or ETL or comparable listed meter with CAT II (or better - III or IV) safety rating. https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/what-are-multimeter-cat-safety-ratings